# Combining SQL join with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `registered` and `attended`, each with two columns: `AttendentId` and `SessionId`. I would like to query the count of `AttendantId` from these two tables individually for a particular session id.

Example:

#### registered

```
AttendantId      SessionId    
ID1              SN1    
ID2              SN2
ID3              SN1
ID4              SN3
```

#### Attended

```
AttendantId       SessionId    
ID1               SN1   
ID4               SN3
```

And I want to obtain the following output:

```
Count(Registered)   Count(Attended)  Session ID    
2                   1                SN1    
1                   0                SN2 
1                   1                SN3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add to your question so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: The headings for the first two columns in your example output are mixed up.

Comment: I tried using join based on Session ID but it is returning cross product of Attendant ID's

Comment: What is the relationship between the session ids in registered and those in attended?  Are the attended session ids always a subset of those in registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select count(distinct registered), 
       count(distinct attended), 
       SessionId
from (select AttendantId registered, null attended, SessionId
      from registered
      union all
      select null registered, AttendantId attended, SessionId
      from Attended) sq
group by SessionId
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select 
  coalesce(a.sessionid, r.sessionid) sessionid,
  count(r.AttendantId) countRegistered,
  count(a.AttendantId) countAttended
from registered r
full outer join attended a
  on r.sessionid = a.sessionid
  and r.AttendantId = a.AttendantId
group by coalesce(a.sessionid, r.sessionid);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ef3a/9)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(ACount, 0),
    ISNULL(RCount, 0),
    X.SessionId
FROM
    (
    SELECT SessionId FROM Registered
    UNION -- implies DISTINCT
    SELECT SessionId FROM Attended
    ) X
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS RCount, SessionId
     FROM Registered
     GROUP BY SessionId) R ON X.SessionId = R.SessionId
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACount, SessionId
     FROM Attended 
     GROUP BY SessionId) A ON X.SessionId = A.SessionId
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd015/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select 
   a.sessionId, 
   case when aCnt is null then 0 else acnt end, 
   case when bCnt is null then 0 else bcnt end
from
   (select 
       sessionId, 
       count(*) aCNt 
   from 
       tbl1 
   group by 
       sessionid) a
full join
   (select 
       sessionId, 
       count(*) bCnt 
   from 
       tbl2 
   group by 
       sessionid) b
on 
   a.sessionId = b.sessionid
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2062e/6)**:

```
| SESSIONID | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 |
-----------------------------------
|       SN1 |        2 |        1 |
|       SN2 |        1 |        0 |
|       SN3 |        1 |        1 |
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all session ID's exist in registered table

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN a.attendentid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end) AS Count(registered), 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN b.attendentid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end) AS Count(attended), 
       a.sessionid 
FROM   registered a 
       INNER JOIN attended b 
               ON a.sessionid = b.sessionid 
GROUP  BY a.sessionid
```